# Netsuite Phptoolkit Could not determine customer compid

Tags: php, netsuite, suitescript2.0, php-toolkit

Trying to get the customer information using phptoolkit
Here's my code:

```
function getCustomer(){
  $service = new NetSuiteService();

  $request = new GetRequest();
  $request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
  $request->baseRef->account_id = "252206";
  $request->baseRef->type = "customer";
  $getResponse = $service->get($request);

  if (!$getResponse->readResponse->status->isSuccess) {
     echo "GET ERROR";
  } else {
     $customer = $getResponse->readResponse->record;
     echo "GET SUCCESS, customer:";
     echo "\nCompany name: ". $customer->companyName;
     echo "\nInternal Id: ". $customer->internalId;
     echo "\nEmail: ". $customer->email;
  }
}
```

And getting error like this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] Could not determine customer compid in phptoolkit/NSPHPClient.php:338 Stack trace: #0 phptoolkit/NSPHPClient.php(338): SoapClient->__soapCall('get', Array, NULL, Array) #1 phptoolkit/NetSuiteService.php(145953): NSPHPClient->makeSoapCall('get', Object(GetRequest)) #2 netsuite.php(23): NetSuiteService->get(Object(GetRequest)) #3

Comment: also tried  $request->baseRef->internalId= "252206" is not workig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the netsuite documentation
`RecordRef` only accept `internalId` and `type`

```
$request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
$request->baseRef->internalId = "252206";
$request->baseRef->type = "customer";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the company ID and put it in your settings file. Also need user email address, password, role Internal ID and app ID. These are used to create a passport.

If your integration uses token based authorization, the requirements are different.

Look in the samples in the toolkit.